# Tic Tac Toe Programming

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

I am pretty new in C++ programming. I am coding for Tic Tac Toe game to understand how its algorithm works. My question is about I have two functions. One of them is clearBoard function and the other one is drawBoard function. I got little help about them but I couldnt figure it out the way those functions works. Can anyone simply explain me what is exactly what? I have been trying to solve it and understand it but I think I got more confused. It might be a piece of cake but I really want to understand what's exactly going on. Thanks for your time and attention...

Here clearBoard function:

```
void clearBoard(int board[])
{
 int i;
  for(i = 0; i < board_size; i++) {
   board[i] = -i - 1;
 }
}
```

And here is my drawBoard function.

```
 void drawBoard(int board[])
 {
  int i, j;
  int n = 0;
  for(i = 0; i <= 6; i = i+3) {
   for(j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
    if(board[i + j] == 2)
    cout << "|X|";
     else if(board[i + j] == 1)
    cout << "|O|";
     else
    cout << "|" << n << "|";
     n = n+1;
    }
   cout << endl;
   }
  }
```

This is my main.cpp file. I just wanted to post my entire work at least it will be easier to see complete picture.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <ctime>
 #include<cstdlib>
 #include "Define.h"
 using namespace std;


 int main()
 {
  int board[board_size];
  int turn = 0;
  int p = 0;
  int move = 10;
  srand(time(NULL));
  clearBoard(board);


  cout << "This turn is randomly chosen!" << endl;
  p = random(2) + 1;
  cout << "The first move goes to Player: " << p << endl;
  turn = p;

  do {
   if(p== 2 && 2 == turn)
  {
    drawBoard(board);
    move = getPlayerMove(turn);
  }
  else
    move = makeRandMove(turn);
  } while(!isMoveValid(board, move));
    board[move] = turn;

 while(!isWin(board, move)){
 drawBoard(board);
  if(2 == turn)
    turn = 1;
  else
    turn = 2;
  do {
   if(2 == turn)
      move = getPlayerMove(turn);
  else
    move = makeRandMove(turn);
  } while(!isMoveValid(board, move));
   board[move] = turn;
  }
  drawBoard(board);
  cout << "Player " << turn << " wins." << endl;
  return 0;
  }
```

And this is the functions.cpp file that has the functions that I was talking about above.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;


const int board_size = 9;

void clearBoard(int board[])
{
 int i;
  for(i = 0; i < board_size; i++) {
  board[i] = -i - 1;
 }
 }

 int random(int x)
 {
 return rand() % x;
 }

 void drawBoard(int board[])
 {
 int i, j;
 int n = 0;
 for(i = 0; i <= 6; i = i+3) {
  for(j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
    if(board[i + j] == 2)
 cout << "|X|";
  else if(board[i + j] == 1)
cout << "|O|";
  else
cout << "|" << n << "|";
n = n+1;
}
cout << endl;
 }
 }


int getPlayerMove(int player)
{
int move;
cout << "Player " << player << " enter move: ";
cin >> move;
return move;
}


int makeRandMove(int player)
{
cout << "Computer (player " << player << ") moving." << endl;
return rand() % board_size;
}


 bool isMoveValid(int board[], int move)
 {
  if(board[move] < 0)
  return true;
  return false;
  }


  bool isWin(int board[], int move)
  {
  if((board[0] == board[1] && board[0] == board[2]) ||
 (board[3] == board[4] && board[3] == board[5]) ||
 (board[6] == board[7] && board[6] == board[8]) ||
 (board[0] == board[3] && board[0] == board[6]) ||
 (board[1] == board[4] && board[1] == board[7]) ||
 (board[2] == board[5] && board[2] == board[8]) ||
 (board[0] == board[4] && board[0] == board[8]) ||
 (board[2] == board[4] && board[2] == board[6]))
  return true;
  return false;
 }
```

And here is my define.h header file has all the protypes...

```
#ifndef formula
#define formula

const int board_size = 9;
int random(int x);
void clearBoard(int board[]);
void drawBoard(int board[]);
int getPlayerMove(int player);
int makeRandMove(int player);
bool isMoveValid(int boardp[], int move);
bool isWin(int board[], int move);

#endif
```

Comment: Make small changes and then run it. See if what happens is what you expected to happen

Comment: If you are new to C++, taking a piece of uncommented, poorly written C-with-`cout`/`cin` and trying to make sense of it is not the way to go. (Seriously. There is very little in this code that is actually showcasing *C++*, and even as C it would fail a code review outright as it *does* showcase a double handful of really bad habits.) I strongly recommend using a good *book*. Not an online tutorial -- too many of those were written by people *while they were learning the language themselves*.

Comment: go step by step function by function.. try commenting out code. Add `cin/cout` at places. Run it in a debugger apply breakpoints. That will help in understanding. Keep documenting your understanding in code itself.

Comment: as DevSolar mention - pick a good book to learn the basics of a language before reading through online examples...

Comment: To elaborate on "bad habits": Always use `{}` for `if` / `while` blocks, even if they are one-liners. Use *consistent* indenting; four spaces are recommended. *Do* write comments about what you expect a piece of code to achieve. (Source: How. Comments: What. Documentation: Why.) If you feel the need to use "magic numbers" (like in in `drawBoard()`), make them named constants so it is clear what they stand for. If this had been done, the code would probably *already* make quite some sense even to you. It hasn't been done. Is this the example you want to learn from?

Comment: I will agree with the others, always pick a good book before jumping to a complex language like C++. Also you should indent your code properly, you have a huge amount of mistakes because you don't use braces for your if statements.

Comment: DevSolar- These codes are all mine. Except clearBoard and drawBoard functions. The person who coded them tried to explained it to me, I got it at first but later on I got confused again

Comment: Indenting: Try [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net) on your sources. `astyle --style=ansi --indent-classes --indent-switches --indent-preprocessor --indent-namespaces --pad-paren-in --pad-header --unpad-paren --convert-tabs --break-blocks --add-brackets --align-pointer=middle --formatted --quiet` -- that tool helps a *lot*.

Comment: DevSolar-Every day I learn new things about c++. This was another one. I just checked this astyle link that you have posted. I will definetely read it and get some hints about it. Thanks for your time. I feel like I am wasting your time guys.

Comment: @user3582393: Never mind. We all started somewhat dump. I, personally, took quite a long time staring at a (otherwise really good) book tutorial before I finally figured out how pointers were supposed to work. (Jeez, that's been a *loooong* time ago. :-D ) If you *heed* the advice you're getting, our time is not wasted -- to the contrary. Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to understanding the two board functions you are having difficulty with, clearBoard and drawBoard, you need to understand the data structure that you're storing your game board in. This is, in fact, a pretty simple example. Your board is defined as an array of 9 items:

```
int board[board_size];
...
const int board_size = 9;
```

The best way to think about this is if you take your 3 x 3 tic-tac-toe game board, and lay each row side by side. So the first three elements are the first row, the next three are the second row, and the last three are the final row.

The drawBoard function is the more complex of the two functions, but if you understand what the array is and what it represents, it makes this function much more understandable. The outer for loop is looping through each "row" of the gameboard, while the inner for loop loops through each element in that row.

Comment: for example take a look at for loop in clearBoard function... how is that possible board[0]=0-1, board[1]=-1-1; board[2]=-2-1; board=[3]=-3-1 on and on. Ends board[8]=-8-1; what is the purpose of it?

Comment: The key here is to look at the interaction between clearBoard and drawBoard; drawBoard only looks at two possible values of the slot on the game board (1 or 2), otherwise it immediately overwrites the value that is in there. Honestly, that line in clearBoard is silly and unnecessary, and could just as easily have been board[n] = 0 to achieve the same effect.